# How can I call an Apache Ignite Service running on a Java node from a .NET client in client mode

Tags: ignite

On the .net side, this just hangs. MyService is only deployed on the Java side.

```
var svc = Ignite.GetServices().GetServiceProxy<MyService>("MyService");
```

Do I need to do something special on the Java side or the .NET side to access the Java service from .NET side? It's also important that the .NET side is running in client mode. We don't want the GUI to participate in persistent storage or compute.

Apparently this is fixed, but I can't find any documentation on how to use it.
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-2686

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I've added documentation:
https://apacheignite-net.readme.io/docs/calling-java-services

Main requirement is to have Java service class in classpath on all nodes (including .NET client node). This should be addressed in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-975.

Other than that it is quite flexible, you just need an interface in .NET with same signature as in Java service.